# Why is it preferred to use immutable objects as elements of a Set?

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, set, immutability

I read it [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20140528113353-16837833-6-benefits-of-programming-with-immutable-objects-in-java):

> Immutable objects are good Map keys and **Set elements**, since these
>   typically do not change once created.

Comment: Map and set implementations typically use the state of elements in order to store them. If that state changes, you make it difficult/impossible to relocate them afterwards. With immutable objects, that is not possible.

Comment: Other languages even make it mandatory that their equivalents of Map keys and Set elements be immutable. For example, C++ `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` keys are `const`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis By state, you mean data (instance fields) of the object right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because these collections rely on hashing, fields that contribute to their `hashCode` should be immutable.

When a `HashMap` wants to store a key-value, it uses hashCode of its `key` and works out a place for the pair,

The same technique will be used for elements retrieval ( ex: contains,get, etc..). Now imagine `hashCode` upon element retrieval produces a value different than the one produced at the time the elements were added ? Would we be able to locate the element correctly? No.

`HashSet` is no different from a `HashMap`.

It's all about having a `hashCode` and `equals` methods that are able to compare objects correctly, immutability makes it easier to reason about the correctness of these methods.

Comment: This also applies to non-hash-based Maps and Sets like TreeMap and TreeSet, where item placement works by `compare` or `compareTo` results and anything that would change the comparison results breaks the data structure.